# How to fetch with parameters using React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

For the sake of this question let's first assume existence of such entity:

```
export interface Event {
    id: number;
    date: Date;
}
```

Then let's assume there's backend with such endpoints:

```
GET /events -> returns all events
GET /events?startDate=dateA&endDate=dateB -> returns all events between dateA and dateB
```

I create hook containing 4 methods (one for each CRUD operation) in my frontend code like this:

```
export function useEvents() {
    const getEvents() = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`events`);
        return response.data;
    }
    const postEvent()...
    const updateEvent()...
    const deleteEvent()...

    const query = useQuery('events', getEvents);
    const postMutation = ...
    const updateMutation = ...
    const deleteMutation = ...

    return { query, postMutation, updateMutation, deleteMutation }
}
```

This architecture works like a charm but I got to the point where I would like to conditionaly fetch events based on currently chosen month in my `Calendar.tsx` component.

How would I inject this information into `useQuery()` and `getEvents()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the query key should contain all "dependencies" that you need for your fetch. This is documented [in the official docs here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key), and I've also [blogged about it here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#treat-the-query-key-like-a-dependency-array).

So, in short:

```
const getEvents(month) = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`events/${month}`);
  return response.data;
}

const query = useQuery(['events', month], () => getEvents(month));
```

The good thing is that react-query will always refetch when the key changes, so data for every month is cached separately, and if the month changes, you'll get a fetch with that month.

Comment: Could you explain best way to use it with they way my hook is constructed? Because now if I want to access query data I do: `const { query } = useEvents()`. How would I pass month here?

Comment: const { query} = useEvents(month) ?

Comment: @TkDodo what to do for scenerios where your is data not available already ? data is only made on event click and i need to call function that does a refetch with new data as parameter ?

Comment: same thing: you put that data into the query key and let react-query refetch automatically.